# javascript to change form data not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following code that when i change the drop down it doesnt matter which i choose it always puts the first part as the selected....

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeValue(){ 
  var option=document.getElementById('block').value; 

if(option=="1"){ 
        document.getElementById('a').value="18005551212"; 
        document.getElementById('b').value="PW"; 
} 
    else if(option=="2"){ 
        document.getElementById('a').value="5551212"; 
        document.getElementById('b').value="Collector"; 
    } 
if(option=="3"){ 
        document.getElementById('a').value="3"; 
        document.getElementById('b').value="3"; 
    } 

    else if(option=="4"){ 
        document.getElementById('a').value="4"; 
        document.getElementById('b').value="4"; 
    } 

} 
</script> 
<form method="post">
<table>  <tr><b>Add new data using form below</b></tr>       
 <tr><td>  Keyword:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td> Block?: </td><td><select name="block" id="block" onchange="changeValue();"> 
<option id="block1" value="1">Block 1</option>
 <option id="block2" value="2">Block 2</option>
 <option id="block3" value="3">Block 3 </option>
 <option id="block4" value="4">Block 4</option>
 <option id="block5" value="5">Block 5</option>
</select><br></td></tr>
<tr><td> Phone #:</td><td> <input type="text" name="phone" id="a"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td> Reason: </td><td> <input type="text" name="reason" id="b"><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td> </td><td align="left"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit  Data"></td></tr>
    </table>
      </form>
```

So when i select option 2 it should show collector and phone #...

Comment: If you'd like a quicker response to this problem you should really put up a "working" example on something like jsfiddle.net instead of posting a huge code bomb. This will keep people from having to do it themselves just to figure out what you want them to solve.

Comment: [It does.](http://jsbin.com/udirot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `<td colspan="2">` in your first row, but regardless, your code works fine. Test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zDg8q/).

Answer (score 0):

Go on jsfiddle.net and paste your code in. The code you provided works.